# How to prevent mailbox access during Exchange migration?

Tags: exchange-2007, mailbox

I am doing a migration of mailboxes from one Exchange 2007 server to another server(new hardware, different server name, both on the same domain).

What steps do I need to take to ensure that no users access the mailbox stores during the migration process?

- Disable port 25?
- Disable OWA?

I will be using the move-mailbox exchange console functionality.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fortunately this is not something you need to worry about. During the migration, there will be short periods where the mailbox is not available, but there is no chance for data loss.

Regardless, it's usually a good idea to schedule moves for low-usage times to minimize the user annoyance factor.

Comment: I've already mitigated this by ensuring users are not active during this time, but I was advised that even opening a public folder connected to a mailbox store would change the store, and therefore may inhibit the migration process. Is this not the case?

Comment: Yep, @ErikA is correct, I've never needed to disable access during mailbox moves.

Comment: @glasnt I've never heard of that issue.  I've always had users using Exchange data during migrations of same version and different versions of Exchange.  It's designed for zero downtime migrations.

Comment: Horray, Exchange isn't as scary as I thought it was! Cheers.

Comment: glasnt: No, Exchange is plenty scary... just not in this scenario.